# Print out Document Information Panel info with document?

Tags: document, word, dip

I have a library with an MS Word document defined as a custom content type. This content type has a few columns defined, which which display in the Document Information Panel, and users fill in when submitting the document.

When a user views that document in MS Word, is there any way for them to print out the information in the Document Information Panel along with the document itself?

This is SharePoint 2010, and the MS Word document is Word 2010.

Comment: Does anybody know how to accomplish this? I have a similiar type of requirement, but on SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Try this: Open up the Word document. Go to File > Options > Display. Under "Printing options" select "Print document properties". Print out the document. The properties (and hopefully the DIP info) prints out as the last sheet.

Comment: Would like to know also so we can print 1 clean sheet with all info.